# c# password masking that works when run over ssh

Tags: c#, ssh, console, passwords, command-line-interface

I'm creating a C# CLI tool that needs to be able to execute via remote SSH terminal.

I would like to accept a password input and mask the password (in the same way that `sudo` does).

However, all methods I can find require you to use `Console.ReadKey()` to mask each key stroke, or `Console.SetCursorPosition()` to reset to the cursor and clear the line with `Console.WriteLine()` it after password entry.

These methods don't work over a remote SSH terminal because the 'console' is not available. (Server is running sshd on cygwin, so possibly the issue is with cygwin mintty?)

Does anyone know how to do this in a way that will work?

Thanks!

Comment: How is that console is not available over ssh terminal?

Comment: @Evk Maybe it's not an SSH issue. The server is running cygwin, so maybe the issue is that a console is present in cygwin mintty terminal. I'm not 100% sure to be honest. Either way, I'm looking for an alternative.